# Can a relation has a relation with another relation

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, relation

can we have some thing like following ER?[image]

Is it a technical fault or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a relationship there should be entity by the help of them you can show relation. so it is impossible to make relation without entity.

**In your case if you want to use 2 relationship there should be 1 entity between them.**

Example of real life

suppose you have two relation teacher and student. you can not say like i am teacher and student of XYZ.

But you can say like i am teacher of Xyz and student of abc.

**Typr of relationship**

**One-to-many relationships**

The most common relationship used when creating relational databases.  A row in a table in a database can be associated with one or (likely) more rows in another table.  An example of a one-to-many relationship is a single order has many items on that order.  And since relationships work both ways it is not uncommon to hear reference to many-to-one-relationships as well.

**One-to-one relationship**

A row in a table is associated to one and only one row in another table.  An example of a one-to-one relationship is a person can have one social security number and a social security number can only be assigned to one person.

In most cases there is no need for a one-to-one relationship as the contents of the two tables can be combined into one table.

**Many-to-many relationships**

When one or more rows in a table are associated with one or more rows in another table.  An example of a many-to-many relationship is a table of customers who can purchase many different products and a table of products that can be purchased by many different customers.